# Show that $f_n \to 0$ almost everywhere.

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

> Show that the sequence $\displaystyle f_n = n \chi_{[0, \frac{1}{n}]} \to 0$ almost everywhere.

- If $x < 0$, then $f_n(x) = f_{n+1}(x) =0.$
- If $0 \le x \le \frac{1}{n}$, then $f_n(x) = n < n+1 = f_{n+1}.$
- If $x> \frac{1}{n}$, then $f_n(x) = f_{n+1}(x) = 0.$

Notice that $f_n(x) \to 0$ everywhere except on the interval $[0, \frac{1}{n}]$.

We have $\lambda ([0, \frac{1}{n}]) = \frac{1}{n}$ for every $n$.

However $\frac{1}{n} \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$, i.e. $\lambda([0, \frac{1}{n}]) \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$.

That is, $f_n \to 0$ almost everywhere.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f_n\rightarrow 0$ almost everywhere is equivalent to say that the meausre of  $E=\{x:lim_n f_n(x)\neq 0\}$ is zero, here $E=\{0\}$.

Comment: Do you please mind explaining to me why $E$ only contains $0$? I can't seem to see why it doesn't contain the whole interval $[0, \frac{1}{n}]$? :)

Comment: If $x<0, f_n(x)=0$ so $lim_nf_n(x)=0$, if $x>0$, there exists $N>0$ such that $x>{1\over N}$, this implies that for $n>N, f_n(x)=0$ so $lim_nf_n(x)=0$. If $x=0, f_n(0)=n$.

Comment: Thank you! :). That makes perfect sense! :D. Our old friend Archimedes wins again! :P