# Why does $\int f_n d\lambda$ not converge to zero??

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

> Consider the sequence of functions $f_n = n \chi_{[0, \frac{1}{n}]}$ defined on $\mathbb R$, which is equipped with Lebesgue measure, and take the sigma-algebra of subsets of $\mathbb R$ to be the Borel sigma-algebra.

In a previous question ([found here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1913632/show-that-f-n-to-0-almost-everywhere/1913635#1913635)), I asked for help in showing that $f_n \to 0$ almost everywhere.

I then continued to work out the following: \begin{align*}
  \lim \int f_n d\lambda &= \lim \int n\chi_{[0, \frac{1}{n}]} d\lambda \\
  &= \lim n \int \chi_{[0, \frac{1}{n}]} d\lambda \\ 
  &= \lim n \lambda([0, \frac{1}{n}]) \\
   &= \lim n\frac{1}{n} \\
   &= \lim 1 \\
    &= 1,
  \end{align*}
i.e. $\int f_n d\lambda$ does not converge to zero.

Can anyobody perhaps explain to me why? I understand that $f_n$ is unbounded for $x \in [0, \frac{1}{n}]$ and so we cannot apply the Lebesgue Dominated Convergence Theorem, but I see that we do have that $f$ is monotonically increasing and $f \in M^+$, so should the Monotone Convergence Theorem not apply?

Can somebody perhaps explain to me why it does not converge to zero?

Comment: This is "the" classical example where the hypothesis of Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem  (which would ensure the convergence of the integrals to zero) does not hold, namely, there exists no dominating integrable  function. Recall that a function $g$ dominates a sequence $(f_n)$ is $|f_n|\leqslant g$ for every $n$. Can you show that, with these functions $f_n$, every such $g$ is non integrable?

Comment: Here's the explanation: $f_n \to 0$ point wise  does not imply $\int f_n \to 0.$ Proof: What you just did. This was well known well before Lebesgue's time. The question of "why?" seems strange  to me.

Comment: If $f_n\le g$ for some $g$, then $\sup f_n \le g$. Try to show that $\sup f_n$ is not integrable. @DJS

Answer (score 3):

The sequence $f_n = n\chi_{]0,1/n]}$ is not monotone: when $x\in (1/2,1]$, $f_1(x)=1$ while $f_n(x) = 0$ for all $n\ge 2$. The only convergence result you can use is the [Fatou's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fatou%27s_lemma),
$$\int_0^1 f  \le \liminf_{n\to \infty} \int_0^1 f_n ,$$
but it says nothing interesting.